# Limit fields available for editing using Razor pages and Entity framework CORE with ViewModel

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

User class

```
public class MyUser {
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string PWD { get; set; }
}
```

Password edit page

```
    public class EditPasswordModel : PageModel {

        [BindProperty]
        public UserMain objRecord { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync() {
            objRecord = await _context.MyUser
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserID == 666);
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() {

            _context.Attach(objRecord).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
```

In this password changing page, I only want to update the `PWD` field.
The option to reload the record from the table in `OnPostAsync()` then copy everything over into objRecord except for `PWD` works, but feels wrong and wasteful.

I've used ViewModels to extend what's brought into a View, combining classes to be used in the View for example, but is there a way to use a ViewModel to limit which fields are available?